# How to implement a List within a map for hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I have a working terminal application, and implementing Hibernate DB now.
Wonder how the following is done properly:

A enclosing object `BookStore` holds a list of orders, grouped by type.

```
class BookStore {
    Map<BookType, List<Order>> orders;
}
```

When switching to Hibernate, I cannot use List within a map. So I would have to introduce another Object, like:

```
class OrderList {
    List<Order> orders;
}
class BookStore {
    Map<BookType, OrderList> orders;
}
```

But is this suitable?
Would it be better to just let the bookstore hold an unsorted list of all orders, and fetch them if needed with a sql statement, like: `SELECT * FORM order o WHERE o.ordertype=OrderTypeA`

with:

```
class BookStore {
    List<Order> orders;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not de-normalise and add the relevant `BookType` field(s) to the `Order` class, such that you'll only have a `List` of `Order` objects in your `BookStore` and you'll be able to easily know how many `Orders` of a certain `BookType` are in a given `BookOrder`, etc. You waste some space but the read operations will be faster. The only downside is that the write operations might get heavier (than with your initial, normalized model), but that might not be a real issue depending on the actual complexity of said write operation, and how often it happends as opposed to (now improved) read operations.